# display checkbox list on selecting value of dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, checkbox, default-value, html-select

I want to display checkbox list on selecting one fix value of dropdown list:
javascript:

```
function getDays(){
        var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if(selectedString == 4)
        {
            document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Html:

```
<b>Please enter days required</b><br/>
        <select name="days" id="days" style="width:200px;" onchange="getDays()">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Mon-Fri</option>
            <option value="2">Mon-Fri</option>
            <option value="3">Mon-Fri</option>
            <option value="4">Bespoke Days</option>
        </select><br/><br/>
        <div id="days_target" style="display:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="mon">Mon &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="tue">Tue<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="wed">Wed &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="thr">Thr<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="fri">Fri &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sat">Sat<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sun">Sun<br/><br/>
        </div>
```

but it doesn't work.what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `getDays` you are using a variable `select` but it is not defined. Solution is to pass the `select` instance when the `onchange` is called like `onchange="getDays(this)`.

Also I think you may have to hide the checkbox list if any other option is selected.

```
<b>Please enter days required</b><br/>
<select name="days" id="days" style="width:200px;" onchange="getDays(this)">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Mon-Fri</option>
    <option value="2">Mon-Fri</option>
    <option value="3">Mon-Fri</option>
    <option value="4">Bespoke Days</option>
</select><br/><br/>
<div id="days_target" style="display:none;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="mon"/>Mon &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="tue"/>Tue<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="wed"/>Wed &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="thr"/>Thr<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="fri"/>Fri &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sat"/>Sat<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sun"/>Sun<br/><br/>
</div>
```

And

```
function getDays(select){
    var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    if(selectedString == 4)
    {
        document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "block";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LbF4X/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by passing the value of the select:

html:

```
<b>Please enter days required</b><br>
        <select name="days" id="days" style="width:200px;" onchange="getDays(this.value)">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">Mon-Fri</option>
            <option value="2">Mon-Fri</option>
            <option value="3">Mon-Fri</option>
            <option value="4">Bespoke Days</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <div id="days_target" style="display:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="mon">Mon &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="tue">Tue<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="wed">Wed &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="thr">Thr<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="fri">Fri &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sat">Sat<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="day" value="sun">Sun<br><br>
        </div>
```

js:

```
function getDays(value){
        if(value == 4)
        {
            document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```